# I need a V_LOOKUP to join two values together from two separate cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

E.G.  in cell A2 I have value OSAS205677 and in cell C2 I have value WKWP0101. I would like to join the together as OSAS205677WKWP0101_B.

I also need to add _B at the end. so the final value should be OSAS205677WKWP0101_B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use concatenate() or the & like so:

```
=A2&C2&"_B"
```

Or:

```
=concatenate(A2,C2,"_B")
```

If you need to look in lists then vlookup() or xlookup() or even index() with match() will work.